# Is it possible to react to a VBScript msgbox from a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, msgbox, wsh

I've been working to make manual processes more of a one-click process and I've run into an issue with these msgbox popups from a VBScript script.

Essentially, I am using PowerShell and doing something like:

```
foreach ($loc in $locs):
    & cscript $loc
```

Where the $loc in $locs is a variable holding the path of a .vbs file that needs to be run.

The issue is that one of our developers included two msgbox statements in each of the .vbs files and those pop up and require you to click <kbd>OK</kbd>.  It would be trivial to edit the VBScript scripts and remove these, but I do not want to change our developers' scripts - so the question is:  is it possible to make PowerShell react to the msgbox(s) that are generated from the *cscript* line?

I'm not sure how I would bring the box into context or react to it via PowerShell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the scripts in batch mode. This will prevent any prompt from stalling execution:

```
foreach ($loc in $locs){
    & cscript //B $loc
}
```

From the `cscript /?` usage message:

```
Usage: CScript scriptname.extension [option...] [arguments...]

Options:
 //B         Batch mode: Suppresses script errors and prompts from displaying
 //D         Enable Active Debugging
 //E:engine  Use engine for executing script
 //H:CScript Changes the default script host to CScript.exe
 //H:WScript Changes the default script host to WScript.exe (default)
 //I         Interactive mode (default, opposite of //B)
...
```

Comment: So much time went into overthinking that.  I'll give this a try, but it looks that it probably should work.

Comment: I tried this and I'm going to accept the answer because it answers the question as asked.  I cannot use this though because the vbs in turn calls sqlplus and sqlldr and those don't execute with this switch.